# Windows Vista wont bootr

Tags: windows-vista

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 with Vista. It will not boot it goes into chkdsk and and keeps repeating, it says press any key to cancel but it does not cancel. How do I cancel chkdsk?

Answer (score 0):

Check the steps from here:

**Disable or Stop Auto CHKDSK During Windows Startup**

http://www.raymond.cc/blog/disable-or-stop-auto-chkdsk-during-windows-startup/

or this:

**How to disable the CHKDSK - Check Disk, on start up for Windows 7**

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-disable-the-chkdsk-check-disk-on-start-up/35f58c69-7a6c-4e1b-aec3-26d7131ec643